# Установка нескольких ОС на VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

Поставил на VirtualBox Windows 7, еще хочу поставить вдобавок Linux, это реально? Или посоветуете оставить одну ОС на VirtualBox?

Comment: Т.е. у вас на виртуалке стоит винда и вы туда же хотите поставить еще и линукс? А зачем? Может быть стоит создать вторую виртуалку чисто с линуксом? Их ставить вместе имеет смысл только если вы хотите потренироваться ставить их вместе (чтобы потом такое же на своем компе провернуть)

Comment: "Кто на ком стоял?" (ц) Какая у вас host-система?

Comment: я хочу поставить еще Linux, разумеется отдельно.

Comment: @Gasket: А host-система какая? Ну, основная, которая без виртуальной машины?

Comment: host-система windows 8.1

Comment: @Gasket: А, понял. Ну, ничего не мешает иметь сколько угодно «гостевых» систем. Смело ставьте отдельной системой линукс. ВЫ сможете параллельно запускать в одном окне семёрку, в другом линукс, работает, хватило бы мощности процессора.

Comment: Ага спасибо буду ставить )

Answer (score 2):

Можешь ставить сколько душе угодно. [image: введите описание изображения здесь]